# Как добавить массив символов в конец строки

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некая программа, в которой в процессе поиска файлов в конец пути вновь найденного файла должна добавляться нумерация 1,2,3 и т.д.

Мучаюсь уже третий день, ничего не получается никак не могу сконкатенировать строки ни в ручную через цикл, ни через lstrcatW.
Думал создать просто "int test" и с инкрементом через преобразование в типу "(LPWSTR) test" прогнать, но тоже не получилось. Решил через перебором массива символов но опять не выходит т.к. lstrcatW требует указатели.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    wchar_t mass[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0};
    wchar_t path = L"C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\";

    for(int i=0; i!=10; i++){
        lstrcatW(path, mass[i]);
        wcout << path << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или так (100 в `path` — число с потолка; главное, чтоб места для добавляемых символов хватало):

```
const wchar_t * mass[] = {L"0", L"1", L"2", L"3", L"4", L"5", L"6", L"7", L"8", L"9"};
wchar_t path[100] = L"C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\";

for(int i=0; i!=10; i++){
    lstrcatW(path, mass[i]);
    wcout << path << endl;
}
```

Comment: Это то что нужно.
Я подозревал что нужно было L расставить и " вместо '.
Да верно цифры копятся но можно через цикл прокинуть с конца и обрезать до слеша.

А как еще такое сделать как я писал через int, например что то типа:
int counter = 0;
while(counter != 10){
lstrcatW(path, (LPCWSTR)counter);

Comment: `L"C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\0123456789"` - почему так нельзя было?

Comment: Все получилось как нужно! Написал функцию где итерировал mass но по выходе из функции нужно было как то запомнить позицию смещения, поэтому пришлось объявить переменную глобально через extern. Возможно ее можно было объявить в main и как то через указатель передать, но у меня не получилось, поэтому так.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> wchar_t path = L"C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\";
> ```

```
wchar_t path[256] = L"C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\";
```

> ```
> for(int i=0; i!=10; i++){
>     lstrcatW(path, mass[i]);
>     wcout << path << endl;
> }
> ```

```
lstrcatW(path, mass);
wcout << path << endl;
```